# Best practices for large JOINs - Warehouse or External Compute (e.g. Spark)

Tags: join, self-join, snowflake, apache-spark

I am working on a problem that requires a very large join. The JOIN itself is pretty straightforward but the amount of data I am processing is very large. I am wondering for very large JOINs, is there a preferred type of technology. For example, is it more effective to a Data Warehouse (like Snowflake) or in some other MPP system like Spark?

To make the problem more concrete I created a hypothetical problem similar to my actual problem. Assume I have a table that looks like this:
[image]

I am working on some logic that requires account pairs that have the same name. To find pairs of accounts with the same account I can easily do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    account1.name, 
    account2.name
FROM accounts as account1
JOIN accounts as account2 ON account1.name = account2.name AND account1.acount_id != account2.acount_id
```

The problem I am facing is due to the amount of data I am processing. There are roughly ~2 trillion records I am trying to self JOIN on. Obviously, this will take some time and some pretty serious compute. I have run a similar query in Snowflake using XL and 3XL warehouses but after several hours of running, I canceled them. I am hoping there is a more cost-effective or time-efficient way.

Has anyone had success with massive JOINs? Are there any other tricks I could deploy? What tool did you find the most effective?

Comment: This isn't really a problem solvable by changing the tool, rather it's one that is by change in process, architecture, or hardware. For example, hashing the name, indexing that hash, and pre-staging the materialized results are techniques to help you solve this problem. Those are all techniques generally applicable to most database systems. After properly architecting your system and improving your process, it just becomes a numbers game with the amount of data you have. E.g. 1 terabyte of data = 1 terabyte of data, no matter what system you use to store it.

Comment: @J.D. Actually there are important architectural supports for large joins in some database systems that are simply not available in others. This is a valid question.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects In all modern mainstream database systems, and I'm sure also in Snowflake, employ pretty much the same techniques for handling joins with large datasets. In fact, even the novelty join methodology you mentioned in your answer uses essentially the same standard algorithms under the hood as the typical physical join operators of other systems. I never said OP's question was invalid, rather offered one way to help solve his problem architecturally.

Comment: J.D.  Please provide evidence that any of the other systems support the specific approach mentioned in my answer.  I would be more than glad to learn that others do: but making assumptions ("I'm sure") does not cut it.  Even getting `spark` 's support to work is arduous and it does explicitly support it.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects I didn't say the specific approach is exactly available among other systems but under the hood of the operation you referenced is either a Hash or Merge Join of sorts which are natively implemented in all modern mainstream relational database systems. While I'm sure the exact operation you speak of has been fine tuned for specific use cases to improve performance by a degree, it's nothing revolutionary, else it'd be the standard. I say this as someone who has worked with and joined tables in the 10s of billions, on modest hardware, regularly.

Comment: @J.D. You are correct that the underlying method is a universal one:  `Sort-Merge-Join` .  The extent to which the database systems I mentioned optimize it is surprising: up to several orders of magnitude vs other systems.  If you are aware of other systems that provide very fine grained hash joins [on data that does not naturally provide it no less] please do toss it in here; I'm always on the lookout for them.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Again, when architected properly, it's doubtful you'd see orders of magnitudes in gains vs other modern mainstream database physical join operations. Upon my quick reading, I understand it also leverages a partitioning algorithm to it too, which is also another common feature available in the main RDBMS, but is not really one used for performance since it only has a linear performance benefit to it, essentially a gain of `O(n)`. I'd be interested in an actual comparison test that can prove otherwise vs a mainstream RDBMS, such as SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc.

Comment: Yes as you state the speedup is linear in the product of partitions x number of buckets per partitions `P x B`.  That product is typically (1K-10K partitions) x (1K buckets): That gives us the several orders of magnitude improvement.   I was a DBA in MS SQL Server (certified) , Oracle *(certified 8i and 9i) , Postgres, and mysql and only saw larger table joins (>1Meg rows on both sides of the join) for the _sharded_ mysql (running on a cluster with dozens of nodes). Even that was limited to single digit millions of rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140628/discussion-between-j-d-and-westcoastprojects).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether exporting such amount of data would be faster/cheaper.

Instead of self-join I would try sorting or grouping:

```
GROUP by name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

OR

```
WITH cte as (
    select name, row_number() over (order by id partition by name) as rn
)
select name from cte where rn > 1;
```

And choose the biggest warehouse. The smaller warehouse the more spilling to disk, which significantly slows down the execution.